# Why my gridview is not getting expanded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview which could display this kind of data,

[image]

Here the circled part is expected to be repeated. Now I want to put Maximize and minimize facility in `GRIDVIEW`. Rows with common CaseNo's should be collapsed and when I click **+** sign then it should expand common rows.
I tried buttons within template field etc but nothing works, I am new to development.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdviewCaseHearingsDetails" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanging="grdviewCaseHearingsDetails_PageIndexChanging"
                             OnRowCommand="grdviewCaseHearingsDetails_RowCommand" PagerStyle-BackColor="#99CC99" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99CC99" DataKeyNames="pk_CaseHearings_ID"
                                                PagerStyle-Font-Size="12.5px" PagerStyle-ForeColor="Black" PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="grdviewCaseHearingsDetails_RowDataBound"
                                                CssClass="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-responsive scrollable">
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="pk_CaseHearings_ID" HeaderText="S.No" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CaseNo" HeaderText="Case No" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CasePetitioner" HeaderText="Petitioner" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Responder" HeaderText="Responder" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="HearingDate" HeaderText="Hearing Date" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OpeningDate" HeaderText="Initiation Date" />

                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ConcernedOfficeName" HeaderText="Concerned Office" />
```

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Collapsible-Nested-GridView-with-Paging-using-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to use nested gridview or gridview inside a repeater.

i prefer gridview nested in repeater. you can hide duplicate rows (tr's) on row created event of repeater on load and use javascript for show/Hide on '+' click.

Comment: i tried taht but that doesn't work, because it's not necessary the rows will be same

Comment: same row , in the sense same case number. every time row is created save case number in view state. if viewstate value is same as the new row's case number hide it. other wise show it.